# How to access the individual bytes of a c_void_p_Array_8 object in Python3?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm using Python ctypes to call a function from a shared library.
The function is called with a char* buffer in which it writes its result. The return value of the function is the number of bytes written to the buffer.

Calling the function works fine, however i'm struggling to access the individual bytes of the buffer.

I create the buffer and call the function like this:

```
buf = (c_void_p * RECBUFFERSIZE)()
n = functionInLibrary(buf)
```

Now how to read the individual bytes stored in buf?

I already tried using
`cast(buf, c_char_p).value` this yields a bytes object with the contents of buf. BUT it is terminated by the first null-byte in buf.

And this is exactly what i do not want. I need to read the first `n` bytes from buf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found it out myself:

```
cast(buf, POINTER(c_char))[0:n]
```